# How can i get my if else statement to work?

Tags: java

So my problem is this: It displays the wrong message when i tell it to deposit 3. 
Why does it do that?
I always get "Not enough money" everytime.

```
String PAYH1 = scan.nextLine();
if (PAYH1.equals("PAYH1"))
{
    System.out.println("please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit (in Euro's).");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int deposit = s.nextInt();
    int price;
    price  = 2;
    int sum = deposit - price;
    if (sum > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
        System.out.println("You have " + sum + " cent(s) in exchange.");
    }
```

Comment: So `3 - 2` equals?

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (sum < 0)
{
    System.out.println("Not enough money!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
    System.out.println("You have " + sum + " cent(s) in exchange.");
}
```